# Scheduled function to run at the 1st of each month

Tags: c#, timer, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to run a function at the 1st of each month, what is the best way to do that ?

I heard about "Quartz", but i don't know about it, can i do it using Quartz ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html) cron jobs are the way to go. Take a look, you can define and schedule a job to run each 1. of the month.

The example of the cron definition: "0 0 10 1 * ?", each 1. of the month at 10:00am.

Comment: What's the difference between this and Windows Server Scheduled Tasks?

Comment: @RafaelDiaz it is easier to use quartz from .NET, to unit test, to integrate with a logger...